# Python Pandas/tqdm show progress for extract

Tags: python, pandas, tqdm

I have a huge pandas Series of 1007 million string rows. I run a regex extract on it(so the task is row order independent, it can be run in parallel) which takes a few hours and looks like this

```
df["big_string_column"].str.extract(r"Name: (.*), Value: (.*)")
```

or

```
df["big_string_column"].str.extractall(r"Name: (.*), Value: (.*)")
```

this returns a new DataFrame with the 2 capture groups and columns.

Is there a way to use tqdm or something else to show progress for this? :)

Can this be refactored into dataframe.progress_apply which retains the capture groups from regex without major performance hits(since pd.Series.str.extract optimizes the regex) or is there a completely different approach?

Comment: Also always nice if this can be turned into a dask thing, from a pandas.Series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any progress report functionality back from `.str.extract`. Changing it into an `.apply` to use `.progress_apply` might come with bad performance penalties.

It's neither pretty nor a one-liner, but if the work being done is row-independent (no grouping), you can always just split the `df` up into chunks, do the work independently on the chunks, and merge them back together at the end. You can then track the progress by chunk with tqdm.

Something like this:

```
# 1000 sections as an example, may need to adapt to your problem
chunks = np.array_split(df, 1000)

processed = []
for chunk in tqdm(chunks):
    processed.append(chunk.str.extract(r"Name: (.*), Value: (.*)"))

out = pd.concat(processed)
```

Comment: No, i cannot split it into chunks due to the overhead, and the work is row-independent as you can see from the regex, it must apply each regex to a row

Comment: Thanks for the info though, splitting it into chunks involves the overhead of then doing a `pd.concat` and I think your answer will work, since most people don't have enough RAM so they split the dataframe into chunks, but I run a job that spins up a cluster with sufficient RAM of 300Gb and then after the job ~3hrs $10 later it shuts down. I was hoping to see if someone knows of another "nice" way to do this so I upvote but wait for better answers if any.

Comment: `I'm not aware of any progress report functionality back from .str.extract` if this is true I will accept answer eventually.

Comment: Are you talking about time/computation or memory overhead? The memory overhead from chunking could be avoided by carefully using views instead, looping over something like `i in range(0, len(df), 1000)`, then processing `df.iloc[i:i+1000]`. The memory overhead from concat can't be avoided when using `extractall` I believe. With `extract` one might preallocate the df and insert, then there's no need for the concat. And there is of course some time overhead in every case.

Comment: Even if you use views by iloc, you will have to `pd.concat`, remember the output is a DataFrame. I meant time computation primarily for the pd.concat, but in smaller setups with laptop, the memory overhead from virtual memory would be a factor. The output dataframe needs to be one single piece as I have to run `group_by` so no getting past that. And the chunksize would be more like a 10,000,000 instead of 1000. Its always faster to do it in memory, that's why I use the big instance of 300Gb RAM. The disadvantage is I lose the reporting of tqdm(chunks) for around 3hrs.